# How to redirect to some url and also return value to caller function?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, redirect, joomla, return-value

I am working on a joomla MVC component in PHP.
I need following functionality 1) & 2) in one of model.php in my component code.

```
function xyz()
{
 //blah blah
 //1) I have to redirect
 $mainframe->redirect( 'index.php?option=com_abc','');
 //2) and also return value to caller function 
 return $row; 
}
```

How do I achieve this ?

Thanks :)

Comment: to what purpose? when you redirect you are usually ending the current request so why do you need to return a value?

Comment: That's what I need; I want this function to return a value, and at the same time I also want to call other task that will be executed by redirecting to the url.

Comment: should the user be redirected to that page or do you just want to trigger that request?

Comment: Just trigger that request. User stays at same url.

Comment: then just use file_get_contents or curl to fire the request or use a job queue like Gearman

Answer (score 2):

Usually, in the MVC approach, models shouldn't be redirecting the users, that's done on the controllers. On the controller, you can do:

```
$this->setRedirect($url, $optional_message);

// some more code to be executed
```

In that way, the user will be redirected after the current controller's action is completed and not exactly when you call the setRedirect method

but if you really need to do it on the model, you can pass the controller as a parameter there to the model's function and set the redirect from there and return the value:

```
<?php
function xyz($controller)
{

    $controller->setRedirect( 'index.php?option=com_abc','');

    return $row; 
}
?>
```

then, in your controller:

```
$model->xyz($this);
```

Comment: Hello @guilleva , I tried the way you suggested, but it didn't work. I moved redirect to controller. But in controller only one redirect will  be executed.